FileNotFound when creating SparkContext with YARN without HDFS
I'm just getting started with Spark / pyspark and trying to switch the resource manager from Spark Standalone to Hadoop YARN. We're using Minio for storage and so not running HDFS nodes.
The problem is that on construction, SparkContext throws a FileNotFound exception for pyspark.zip by default or one of the jars in the jars list if spark.yarn.jars is set - details below.
I'm testing in docker compose with 1 YARN resource manager image, 1 node manger image, and 1 Spark image.
For the YARN resource and node managers, we're using https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/hadoop 3.3.6 images.
For the Spark installation we're using the https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/spark 3.5.1 image.
Context setup in python:
yarn_url = os.environ.get("YARN_RESOURCE_MANAGER_URL")
yarnparse = urlparse(yarn_url)

conf = SparkConf(
    ).setMaster("yarn"
    ).setAppName("foo123"
    ).set("spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.hostname", yarnparse.hostname
    ).set("spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.address", yarnparse.netloc)

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

In the spark container, YARN_CONF_DIR points at an empty directory.
This throws an exception (full logs at the end of the question):
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1721086963359_0001
failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1721086963359_0001_000002
exited with  exitCode: -1000
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2024-07-15 23:44:20.802]File
file:/home/spark_user/.sparkStaging/application_1721086963359_0001/pyspark.zip
does not exist
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/spark_user/.sparkStaging
/application_1721086963359_0001/pyspark.zip does not exist

If spark.yarn.jars is set then pyspark.zip will just be replaced with one of the jars in the list.
This is a bit mystifying, as presumably either the spark driver or the YARN application manager created this folder based on the app ID, so of course there won't be jars / zip files there unless the driver or AM put them there.
There are no contents in the staging directory in the spark container:
$ docker exec -it spark-dev-notebook bash
spark_user@0532d5015cad:/opt/bitnami/spark$ cd /home/spark_user/.sparkStaging/
spark_user@0532d5015cad:~/.sparkStaging$ ls
spark_user@0532d5015cad:~/.sparkStaging$ 

The resource manager UI has no more information than the driver logs.
The only relevant information in the node manager UI is:

There's no logs on the node manager:
$ docker exec -it yarn-nodemanager bash
bash-4.2$ cd /var/log/hadoop/userlogs/
bash-4.2$ ls
application_1721241833247_0001
bash-4.2$ ls application_1721241833247_0001/
bash-4.2$ 

There's no staging directory on the nodemanager, as you'd expect:
$ docker exec -it yarn-nodemanager bash
bash-4.2$ ls /home
bash-4.2$ 

Same for the resource manager:
$ docker exec -it yarn-resourcemanager bash
bash-4.2$ ls /home
bash-4.2$ cd /var/log/hadoop/
bash-4.2$ ls
bash-4.2$ 

I also tried running in cluster mode for S&Gs with ).set("spark.submit.deployMode","cluster" but spark refuses to run at all in that case and tells you to use spark-submit.
I'm a bit stumped as to how to move forward with debugging this. There's this answer, but the issue there was a local cluster was in use, which isn't applicable here.
Edit: The reason I assumed this setup would work is based on the Spark on YARN documentation. In particular:

To make Spark runtime jars accessible from YARN side, you can specify
spark.yarn.archive or spark.yarn.jars. For details please refer to
Spark Properties. If neither spark.yarn.archive nor spark.yarn.jars is
specified, Spark will create a zip file with all jars under
$SPARK_HOME/jars and upload it to the distributed cache.

and from the spark.yarn.jars description:

List of libraries containing Spark code to distribute to YARN
containers. By default, Spark on YARN will use Spark jars installed
locally...

Full driver logs:
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
24/07/17 19:33:55 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
24/07/17 19:33:56 WARN Utils: spark.executor.instances less than spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors is invalid, ignoring its setting, please update your configs.
24/07/17 19:33:57 WARN Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.
24/07/17 19:34:04 ERROR YarnClientSchedulerBackend: The YARN application has already ended! It might have been killed or the Application Master may have failed to start. Check the YARN application logs for more details.
24/07/17 19:34:04 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1721244785338_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1721244785338_0001_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2024-07-17 19:34:03.598]File file:/home/spark_user/.sparkStaging/application_1721244785338_0001/pyspark.zip does not exist
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/spark_user/.sparkStaging/application_1721244785338_0001/pyspark.zip does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:915)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:1236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:905)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.verifyAndCopy(FSDownload.java:275)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.access$000(FSDownload.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:425)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:422)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1899)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ContainerLocalizer$FSDownloadWrapper.doDownloadCall(ContainerLocalizer.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ContainerLocalizer$FSDownloadWrapper.call(ContainerLocalizer.java:240)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ContainerLocalizer$FSDownloadWrapper.call(ContainerLocalizer.java:228)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://b967e49687bc:8088/cluster/app/application_1721244785338_0001 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
. Failing the application.
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.waitForApplication(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:235)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:604)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
24/07/17 19:34:04 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Attempted to send shutdown message before the AM has registered!
24/07/17 19:34:04 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Attempted to request executors before the AM has registered!
24/07/17 19:34:04 WARN MetricsSystem: Stopping a MetricsSystem that is not running

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 11
      4 conf = SparkConf(
      5     ).setMaster("yarn"
      6     ).setAppName("foo123"
      7     ).set("spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.hostname", yarnparse.hostname
      8     ).set("spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.address", yarnparse.netloc)
     10 #spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
---> 11 sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

File /opt/bitnami/spark/python/pyspark/context.py:203, in SparkContext.__init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls, udf_profiler_cls, memory_profiler_cls)
    201 SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
    202 try:
--> 203     self._do_init(
    204         master,
    205         appName,
    206         sparkHome,
    207         pyFiles,
    208         environment,
    209         batchSize,
    210         serializer,
    211         conf,
    212         jsc,
    213         profiler_cls,
    214         udf_profiler_cls,
    215         memory_profiler_cls,
    216     )
    217 except BaseException:
    218     # If an error occurs, clean up in order to allow future SparkContext creation:
    219     self.stop()

File /opt/bitnami/spark/python/pyspark/context.py:296, in SparkContext._do_init(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, jsc, profiler_cls, udf_profiler_cls, memory_profiler_cls)
    293 self.environment["PYTHONHASHSEED"] = os.environ.get("PYTHONHASHSEED", "0")
    295 # Create the Java SparkContext through Py4J
--> 296 self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
    297 # Reset the SparkConf to the one actually used by the SparkContext in JVM.
    298 self._conf = SparkConf(_jconf=self._jsc.sc().conf())

File /opt/bitnami/spark/python/pyspark/context.py:421, in SparkContext._initialize_context(self, jconf)
    417 """
    418 Initialize SparkContext in function to allow subclass specific initialization
    419 """
    420 assert self._jvm is not None
--> 421 return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)

File /opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py:1587, in JavaClass.__call__(self, *args)
   1581 command = proto.CONSTRUCTOR_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1582     self._command_header +\
   1583     args_command +\
   1584     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1586 answer = self._gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1587 return_value = get_return_value(
   1588     answer, self._gateway_client, None, self._fqn)
   1590 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1591     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File /opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1721244785338_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1721244785338_0001_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2024-07-17 19:34:03.598]File file:/home/spark_user/.sparkStaging/application_1721244785338_0001/pyspark.zip does not exist
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/spark_user/.sparkStaging/application_1721244785338_0001/pyspark.zip does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:915)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:1236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:905)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.verifyAndCopy(FSDownload.java:275)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.access$000(FSDownload.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:425)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:422)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1899)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ContainerLocalizer$FSDownloadWrapper.doDownloadCall(ContainerLocalizer.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ContainerLocalizer$FSDownloadWrapper.call(ContainerLocalizer.java:240)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ContainerLocalizer$FSDownloadWrapper.call(ContainerLocalizer.java:228)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://b967e49687bc:8088/cluster/app/application_1721244785338_0001 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
. Failing the application.
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.waitForApplication(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:235)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:604)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)


Edit 2:
I tried with spark-submit with the Java example app to see if there was any difference. The long and short of it is regardless of cluster vs client mode, the submit code says it uploaded resources to a specific file path (example: file:/home/spark_user/.sparkStaging/application_1721244785338_0003/__spark_libs__11685370608324626554.zip), and then the job fails because that file path doesn't exist.
Cluster mode:
spark_user@e104a7b098ff:/opt/bitnami/spark$ ./bin/spark-submit \
> --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
> --master yarn \
> --conf spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.hostname=yarn-resourcemanager \
> --conf spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.address=yarn-resourcemanager:8032 \
> --deploy-mode cluster \
> examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.5.1.jar \
> 10

I ran out of space for this answer, so logs are here: https://gist.github.com/MrCreosote/faf5b4c0591ce9f37b6c95f049c38a45
Client mode:
spark_user@e104a7b098ff:/opt/bitnami/spark$ ./bin/spark-submit \
> --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
> --master yarn \
> --conf spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.hostname=yarn-resourcemanager \
> --conf spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.address=yarn-resourcemanager:8032 \
> --deploy-mode client \
> examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.5.1.jar \
> 10

Logs: https://gist.github.com/MrCreosote/a1fd88aaeb70fd0b6ea16ad18e89b91c
Edit 3:
If I include --conf spark.yarn.preserve.staging.files=true in the spark-submit command line, then the library files do exist in the staging directory, but only on the spark node. In this case the logs saying the files were uploaded is a misnomer as it seems they were just copied from /tmp. I'm assuming here that the staging directory needs to be accessible to all nodes. This seems to be different from how the spark standalone cluster works, as setting --jars works there without an issue and without HDFS.
